# Building hash tag support for Jquery Filter Plugin

Tags: jquery, url, hashtag

I wanted a SUPER basic filtering system for my portfolio page so when the user clicks on "branding", just work with a class name of branding shows up (and the rest hide), and when the user clicks on print design, just print shows up, etc.

I have used isotope and quicksand, but this time I wanted a ultra basic way of doing it without any effects. So I chose to use [this script](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/). The jquery is fairly simple - it looks for portfolio items that have the same class as the filter link and show/hide. Here is the jquery:

```
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').show().removeClass('hidden');
    } else {

        $('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
            $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
    }

    return false;
});
```

In my header/nav, I have navigation that includes all of these filterable links. So underneath "work" in the nav, I have all of the filterable objects. When a user clicks on "Branding" they are brought to the work page, with all of the portfolio items showing (not JUST branding items). That is because this jquery script does not have support for hash tags. That is, each state of the filtered portfolio does not have a URL associated with it. I am looking to add this functionality, but am not really sure where to start.

I noticed there is a [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) that seems like exactly the solution I need. Can someone assist me with how to go about adding support for hashtags or using them with this hashchange plugin? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is an example using hashchange that works just great:  http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test1

Comment: As an aside: Why do you show/hide elements *and* add/remove a `.hidden` CSS class? Would the CSS class not be enough?

Comment: If I was to remove the show/hide, the script wouldn't work! Any idea how to integrate a hash/URL for each link?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this is the best way to handle this problem, but the solution I came up with is assigning hashtags to every anchor link in the nav. And hten I applied the following jquery to make it work:

```
var thispage = window.location.hash;

if(thispage == ''){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(1)').addClass('current');
}
if(thispage == '#brand-id'){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(2)').addClass('current');
}
if(thispage == '#print'){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(3)').addClass('current');
}
if(thispage == '#book-and-editorial'){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(4)').addClass('current');
}
if(thispage == '#web'){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(5)').addClass('current');
}
if(thispage == '#packaging'){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(6)').addClass('current');
}
if(thispage == '#exhibit'){
    $('ul#filter li:nth-child(7)').addClass('current');
}

var currentpage = thispage.replace('#','');

$('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass(currentpage)) {
        $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

It seems bloated, but is there a better way to go about this, perhaps building it into the original script?